# What to use in failures and error case: WebApplicationException vs Response?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on Rest service and I am confuse in case of failures/errors should I use `Response` or `WebApplicationException`?

Below is an example where I am using Response to return the 400 Bad Request error message along with a JSON response what went wrong.

```
@GET
@Path("/data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getData(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    String client = getClientId();
    if (client == null || client.isEmpty()) {
        return Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("{\"error\": \"client id is null or empty\"}").build();
    }

    // some code and return succesfull response

    return Response
            .status(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
            .entity(resp.getResponse()).build();
}
```

What is the right thing to do here? If I need to use `WebApplicationException` then how can I use it to return 400 Bad Request error message along with a JSON response

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, *whether to* return a `Response` or throw a mapped exception, I say is just a matter of preference. But there are cases where returning a `Response` is not possible, for instance if you are tied to an interface contract, where the return type is not `Response`, or you are not in the context of a resource method, say in a filter or interceptor.

If you need to throw an exception and it is not possible to return a `Response` (or you'd just rather throw the exception), if you look at the constructors of [`WebApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException.html), you'll notice that it has a constructor that excepts a `Response`. That's really the only way to add a body if throwing an exception (unless you use a [mapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)).